# My background-image getting cut off outside original window display (browser viewport)

Tags: html, css, background-image

I need help with my comming-soon-webpage (swedish) that I am designing and coding; http://www.fjalltunnan.se/

My background-image getting cut off outside original window display (browser viewport). You will see this at the bottom if you resize the broswer window on a comupter or if you visit the webpage from a mobile device, a gray background appear (the body background color #ddd). How can I solve this? I need the background to always be 100% of the viewport, even when resizing the broser window. And keep the footer sticky.

Regards, Patrick

Comment: Can you please add jsfiddle with your code ?

Comment: @tmylamoule There's a link to the actual site provided.

Comment: You need to add some media queries. The problem you're having is that your main title and paragraph below are wrapping and pushing everything down the page.

Comment: @tmylamoule please see the webpage: http://www.fjalltunnan.se/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  although you have provided a link to an example, *if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.*

Comment: @JayMoy Okay. I would like if you could explain more specific. Is there antother way I can code my h1 and paragraph? How can I avoid it to wrap/push everything else down, did you get it to work? How can I solve this with media quires, in what way? I am very thankful for your help Jay.

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you for your suggestions. This is my first post here on stackoverflow. The desired behavior is that I want the background to always cover the entire height of the viewport. The specific problem is that the background does not fill up the entire viewport height (only the body height) when resizing the browser or visit the page on a mobile device. Is there anything more that I can do or that you would like to know to be able to help me? Thank you very much for your help Paulie. /Patrick from Sweden